# Understanding a "computationally convenient uniqueness condition" on loadings in factor analysis

Tags: factor-analysis

In  "Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis"  by Johnson and Wichern, the authors mention a *"computationally convenient uniqueness condition"* $$L^T\psi^{-1}L=\Delta,$$ where $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix. Here, $L$ is the factor loadings matrix and $\psi$ is vector of specific variances.

I cannot understand how this condition removes the multiple choices of $L$ and makes it *unique*. Can anyone help?

Comment: That phrase appears in the context of brief describing the maximum likelihood method of factor extraction. And it is not a term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factor loadings $L$ and the diagonal matrix of specific variances $\Psi$ are chosen to approximate the covariance/correlation matrix $\Sigma$ of your data: $$\Sigma \approx LL^\top + \Psi.$$ We can immediately see that $L$ is not uniquely defined because any $LR$ where $R$ is a rotation matrix would work equally well: $$LR(LR)^\top = LRR^\top L^\top = LL^\top.$$

Your textbook introduces a constraint $$L^\top\Psi^{-1}L = \Delta.$$ If we can find a unique $R$ that would make this constraint true, then it would mean that this constraint fixes the choice of $L$. Let's try. Plugging $LR$ instead of $L$ into the constraint equation, we get $$R^\top L^\top \Psi^{-1} L R = \Delta.$$ Multiplying by $R$ from the left and by its transpose from the right, we obtain $$L^\top \Psi^{-1} L = R\Delta R^\top,$$ which is simply an eigendecomposition of $L^\top \Psi^{-1} L$. So $R$ is given by the matrix of eigenvectors of $L^\top \Psi^{-1} L$. QED.

PS. By the way, do the authors explain why this constraint is "computationally convenient"?

Comment: No I think they don't. Can you add that too for me? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I do not know! I was going to ask you about it :) Have you figured out the bit about singular value decomposition? I have not had the time to reply to that.

Comment: Thanks I have seen some materials about SVD (on how to get it). But it would be great if you could just tell me intuitively what it does. I am actually trying to understand what was meant by 'singular value' here!

Comment: SVD decomposes any matrix into a product of three matrices: orthogonal, diagonal, and orthogonal. It's a mathematical theorem that any matrix can be decomposed like that. So once you see (in the last equation in my answer) that some matrix on the left side is decomposed into $R\Delta R^\top$, you know that it must be SVD decomposition. Actually, I just realized that left-hand side matrix is symmetric, so SVD coincides with eigendecomposition! Which means that $R$ is simply the matrix of eigenvectors of $L^\top \Psi^{-1} L$. I should not have mentioned SVD at all. Sorry.