# The number of free parameters in factor analysis after an orthogonal rotation

Tags: factor-analysis, factor-rotation

**Background**

I'm reading some notes in multivariate data analysis, in particular factor analysis.

- A data vector $X_{p\times 1}$, with $E(X) = \mu$
- A vector $F_{m \times 1} $ of factors,
- A matrix $L_{p\times m}$ of loadings, and
- A vector $\varepsilon_{p \times 1}$ of $p$ errors with a diagonal covariance matrix $Var(\varepsilon) = \Psi$

which gives the model

$$ X-\mu = LF + \varepsilon  $$

The model has $mp + p$ parameters after considering $L$ and $\Psi$.

The solutions are not unique, and are only determined up to orthogonal rotations $L^* = LT$ where $T$ is an orthogonal matrix.  This is used profitably to rotate the factors in a way that provides better interpretation.

**Question**

Then, the notes say:

> after rotating with $T$, there are $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ fewer parameters.

I just can't figure out where that comes from.  Can someone please explain?

Comment: @amoeba No, you're right, I probably don't want it there.  However, I would appreciate either a hint or a full solution.  Whichever gets me closer to understanding.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now, but here is a hint: how many parameters does $T$ have?

Comment: @amoeba Hmm... I thought it was fixed and known, based on what I've read so far.  I'll continue reading, and keep that hint in mind.

Comment: No, the whole point is that you are free to choose any $T$ and the factor analysis solution $L^*$ will be as valid as before. So the question is, how many parameters are there in $T$.

Comment: Hi, I think I figured one thing out.  Observe that, in order for a matrix $T$ to be orthogonal, its columns need to sum to one be mutually orthogonal.  Hence, that gives a system of equations that the elements of the matrix need to satisfy.  I found that $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ parameters are freely varying, in the sense that if you wanted to make an orthogonal matrix, you could start by picking $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}$ elements but then the rest would be determined.  So I kind of get that.  Is that the right direction?

Comment: That's correct. So $T$ has $m(m-1)/2$ parameters and you can choose those freely. It means that you can subtract this number from the number of actual estimated parameters of your model. Do you want to post this as an answer yourself? BTW, I don't quite understand your intro section: usually $X$ is matrix with $n$ data points, each of $p$ dimensions, not just one vector (with one vector you can't really run FA).

Comment: @amoeba I understand that $T$ has $m(m-1)/2$ free parameters and that L is only unique to multiplication by an orthogonal matrix. However, I am unable to understand how these two facts put together reduces the number of free parameters in $L$ by $m(m-1)/2$?

Comment: @kasa I'm not sure what's the best way to show it formally, but the intuition is that $L$ has $mp$ entries in it, but as it's not unique many of these entries can be arbitrarily fixed. If you can choose an arbitrary matrix $T$ with $m(m-1)/2$ free parameters, then this allows you to "fix" $m(m-1)/2$ parameters of $L$, leaving only $mp-m(m-1)/2$ free parameters. Sorry, it's only hand-waving... there must be a better way to show it but I don't see it right now.

Comment: @amoeba Thank you for sharing your intuition. If I find a formal answer, I will share it here.

Comment: @amoebasaysReinstateMonica: I found an answer. Kindly take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I found the following references - [Rotation in Factor analysis by Darton](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2988040?seq=1) and [this presentation](http://www.ams.med.uni-goettingen.de/download/Steffen-Unkel/chap8.pdf) wherein it is stated that because of the rotational indeterminacy, an extra constraint is imposed - primarily for computational convenience.

The extra constraint is usually of the form:  $L^{T} \Psi^{-1} L$ is a diagonal matrix. By construction $L^{T} \Psi^{-1} L$ is a symmetric matrix, and setting the non-diagonal elements to zero is equivalent to a reduction in $m(m-1)/2$ degrees of freedom.

Update:

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146674/understanding-a-computationally-convenient-uniqueness-condition-on-loadings-in?rq=1) by Amoeba explains it in more detail.